# Form Validation - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

index.js

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import Axios from 'axios';
    import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
    import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
    import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

    const AddRequest = () => {
    const [request, setRequest] = useState({
        product_name: '',
        description: '',
        product_img: '',
    });

    const [error, setError] = useState({
        product_error: ''
    })

    const handleChange = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const {name, value} = e.target;
        let formError = {...error};
        switch(name) {
            case "product_error":
            formError.product_error = 
            value.length < 0 ? "Required" : "";
            break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        setError({formError, [name]: value});
        console.log(error)
        setRequest({ ...request, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    const headers = {
        'x-access-token': localStorage.getItem('accessToken'),
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }

    const handleImageChange = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setRequest({ ...request, [e.target.name]: e.target.files });
    };

    const handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData()
        for (const file of request.product_img) {
            formData.append('product_img', file)
        }
        formData.append('product_name', request.product_name)
        formData.append('description', request.description)
        await Axios.post(config.api, formData, {
            headers: headers
        })
            .then(res => {
                toast.success('Added Successfully!', {
                    position: "top-right",
                    hideProgressBar: false,
                    closeOnClick: true,
                    pauseOnHover: true,
                });
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e)
                toast.error('not Added', {
                    position: "top-right",
                    hideProgressBar: false,
                    closeOnClick: true,
                    pauseOnHover: true,
                });
            })
        setTimeout(function () {
            history.push('/')
        }, 1500);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <ToastContainer />
            <form onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)} noValidate>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor='product_name'>Product Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="product_name" id="product_name" placeholder="Enter Product Name" className="form-control" noValidate onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
                    {errors.product_error}
                </div> =====>>> This is required it must give error if left empty
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor='description'>Description:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Description" className="form-control" onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
                </div>
                </div>  =====>>> This is required it must give error if left empty
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor='product_img'>Product Image:</label> <br />
                    <input type="file" multiple name="product_img" id="product_img" onChange={e => handleImageChange(e)} />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success"> Add Request Rekko </button>
            </form>
        </>
    )
    };

   export default AddRequest
```

Everything is working fine but form validation is not working. I am new to react and tried many things but still, it is not working. Can anyone help me with form validation? I only want all 3 fields to be required. It shows the message that this field is required if someone submits a form without entering anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the tag required inside the input, like this:

```
<input type="file" multiple name="product_img" id="product_img" onChange={e => handleImageChange(e)} required />
```

Comment: error message is not displaying. How can I display that?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma shouldn't it be `error` instead of `errors`?

Comment: didn't you get any error message in your terminal because of the `errors` variable inside the html? anyways, try to change that to `error`.

Comment: i think it must be error instead of errors anyhow i have used formik library it does not support image upload so that was the only issue i am facing. It will be great if anyone have good reference for image uploading in formik